# How to make a clone of a bootable USB?

Tags: macos, clone, bootable-media

I have a bootable USB for OSX El Capitan that I got from a friend. I need to make a copy of that on my USB. How do I clone that or make it into an ISO and clone the ISO into my USB in Mac?

Comment: It would seem any disk cloning software should work, whether Clonezilla, Acronis or other. See http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-drive-cloning-software.htm for some more.

Comment: Recommendations for Mac might be more helpful ;-) Super Duper or Carbon Copy Cloner are the usual suspects. Acronis does now make a Mac version, but I'm not very experienced with it - see http://www.macworld.com/article/2461362/drive-cloning-utilities-the-best-mac-apps-for-making-a-bootable-backup.html for a review of the others

Answer (score 16):

You can use the standard UNIX utility `dd`. Plug in the flash drive you want to clone, open Terminal by searching in Spotlight (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>) or by going to Applications → Utilities folder. Now type the following and hit enter:

`dmesg | tail -n 10`

Check what drive shows up. I'll use `sd2` for this example (could be `ada1`, `sda1`, etc. in your case). Now execute:

`sudo dd if=/dev/sd2 of=usb.img bs=4096`

Unplug the flash drive when it's finished. Plug in the blank one and execute:

`sudo dd if=usb.img of=/dev/sd2 bs=4096`

to clone to the blank USB flash drive. It's good practice to verify that the second USB drive was assigned the same device name.

Comment: if you get the error `Resource busy` when writing the image file to usb device, then you'll have to unmount the disk by using diskutility or in terminal using `diskutil unmount /dev/diskX`

Comment: Could you not do it directly from one drive to the other? Say `sudo dd if=/dev/sd1 of=/dev/sd2 bs=4096`?

Answer (score 9):

You should be able to use Disk Utility included with your Mac. Connect both USB drives to your Mac. Then do the following.

1. Click on the Restore tab
2. Drag the source USB drive over to where it says Source
3. Drag the destination USB drive over to where it says Destination
4. Click the Restore button

Comment: Looks like the UI of Disk Utility had changed since this answer was published

Answer (score 8):

You can use the standard UNIX utility `dd`. Plug in the flash drive you want to clone, open Terminal by searching in Spotlight (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>) or by going to Applications → Utilities folder. Now type the following and hit enter:

`diskutil list`

This command will list all the connected internal and external disks. Look for the entry corresponding to your USB drive (it would be labeled as *(external, physical)*) and note the path of the file representing it. The path would be of the form `/dev/disk_x_` where `_x_` would be an integer. In my case, the path for the file representing the external USB disk was `/dev/disk2`. Now run the following command in Terminal.

`sudo dd if=/dev/disk2 of=usb.img bs=4096`

Here, `if` means input file, which is the path of the file representing the USB drive. `of` represents output file (image file) which would be created on your internal hard drive (specifically in the current directory).

Unplug the flash drive when it's finished. Plug in the blank one, determine the path of the filename corresponding to it as explained above (by running `diskutil list`) and execute:

`sudo dd if=usb.img of=/dev/sd2 bs=4096`

Again, the input file (`if`) is changed to the image file that we created in the last step and the output file (`of`) is changed to the path of the file representing the USB disk.

It would be good to verify that the second USB drive was assigned the same device name and check that the copy is identical to the original disk.

Comment: Will this work if the source and target USB sticks are different sizes?

Comment: @Calab Yes. Make sure that the target has enough free space.

Comment: if you get the error `Resource busy` when writing the image file to usb device, then you'll have to unmount the disk by using diskutility or in terminal using `diskutil unmount /dev/diskX`

Comment: I had to use `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskX` when I got `Resource busy` when writing from image file to new usb device

Answer (score 0):

I got the message "disk2 was already unmounted or it has a partitioning scheme so use "diskutil unmountDisk" instead" when using diskutil unmount /dev/diskX
Then I used diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskX to unmount it
However, I don't know if I have to eject and insert the flash drive again or if I should run sudo dd if=usb.img of=/dev/diskX bs=4096 right away with the unmounted flash drive

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).